# MS Access 2010: Extract unique values

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

first off: I know virtually nothing about MS Access but now I'm in a situation where I have to use it (dataset is too big for Excel). The data has column names like Customer_Name, Product Name, Amount, Date

Date refers to the last day of a month, so for example for February it's 28/02/2013. Now I want to compare the amount a customer bought in February to the amount he/she bought in January and calculate the difference. So far, I've been able to this by prompting the user to enter the date.

```
SELECT Data.Customer_Name,   
Sum(IIf(Format(Date,"yymm")=[Startdate (yymm)?],Amount,0)) AS Amount_Startdate, 
Sum(IIf(Format(Date,"yymm")=[Enddate (yymm)?],Amount,0)) AS Amount_Enddate, 
Amount_Enddate-Amount_Startdate AS Difference
FROM Data
GROUP BY Data.Customer_Name;
```

This works but is it possible for Access to recognize which dates are in the column "Date" (there are only two distinct dates) so the user does not have to enter anything? Also, I tried to replace "Amount_Startdate" with a field that has the respective date in its name (e.g. "Amount_Feb2013") and played around with ampersand but it didn't work.

Comment: how about the [DISTINCT](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/all-distinct-distinctrow-top-predicates-HA001231351.aspx) prefix?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new table called tblValues with just 2 fields; ID and TDate (always try to avoid using reserved words like "Date", "System" or other words that Access already assigns a function to), you can fill it like this:

```
ID        TDate 
--        ---------
ST        1/31/2014 
EN        2/28/2014
```

Then you could use the DLookup function to make this code generic:

```
SELECT Data.Customer_Name,   
Sum(IIf(Format(Date,"yymm")=DLookup(Format(TDate, "yymm"), tblValues, "ID = 'ST'"),Amount,0)) AS Amount_Startdate, 
Sum(IIf(Format(Date,"yymm")=DLookup(Format(TDate, "yymm"), tblValues, "ID = 'EN'"),Amount,0)) AS Amount_Enddate, 
Amount_Enddate-Amount_Startdate AS Difference
FROM Data
GROUP BY Data.Customer_Name;
```

Then you could just update the table with the values you want to use as start and end dates whenever you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help but this is not exactly what I am looking for. The columns of the query should look something like this:

Customer_Name, Amount_Feb2014, Amount_Mar2014, Difference

The dates can vary, so for one task I might use data from March 2014 and April 2014, for another task it might be May 2012 and June 2014 (but there are only two distinct dates in the table at any time). So I want Access to identify the dates, use them to name the query-columns (Amount_Feb2014) accordingly and sum the amount over each month. 

Is this possible?

Comment: OK, I changed my answer to take into account what you're saying.  Pretty sure "DLookup()" is the way you want to go.  The problem with pure automation is determining which one is Start and which one is End, unless you ran a sort query before it and just took the unique dates in Ascending order.  It's probably easier if you were doing this in VBA as opposed to queries, as it would give you a little more flexability.